# Kotlin Quasar example not working

Tags: gradle, kotlin, quasar

I am testing the Kotlin Quasar actor example. 
[Quasar and Kotlin – a Powerful Match](http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2015/06/04/quasar-kotlin/)
So the question is, is this example out of date and is there any documentation in which I can find out how to use Kotlin and Quasar?

This is my gradle.build file.

```
group 'no.inmeta.kotlin.akka'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
 }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile "co.paralleluniverse:quasar-kotlin:0.7.4"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I get unresolved reference for import co.paralleluniverse.kotlin.Actor

Comment: Have you tried to build your project from the console? Refreshing the project in IDE? Maybe it's just your IDE complaining? That class is inside one of the referenced JARs and should be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm part of the Quasar team.

The post cites Quasar tests which you can run by cloning the Quasar repo and running e.g. `gradle :quasar-kotlin:build` (requires Gradle installed) but for new projects/experiments I suggest to start instead from the [Gradle template, `kotlin` branch](https://github.com/puniverse/quasar-gradle-template/tree/kotlin) which now uses the latest Kotlin `1.0.1-2` (and for simplicity the latest Quasar `0.7.5-SNAPSHOT` that depends on it).

Starting from that template I built [this project](https://github.com/circlespainter/so-36719303) (more info about how to configure it and run it in the main README) that runs the same Quasar actor tests as normal programs rather than tests. Here's its `build.gradle`:

```
group 'no.inmeta.kotlin.akka'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVer = '1.0.1-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVer"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8     // 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.8     // 1.7

configurations {
    quasar
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()
    }
}

repositories {
//    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases" }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
//    maven { url 'https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}

ext.classifier = ':jdk8' // ':'

ext.quasarVer  = '0.7.5-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    compile "co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:${quasarVer}${classifier}"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVer"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVer"
    compile "co.paralleluniverse:quasar-kotlin:${quasarVer}"

    quasar "co.paralleluniverse:quasar-core:${quasarVer}${classifier}@jar"
}

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = [
    "-Dco.paralleluniverse.fibers.verifyInstrumentation=true",
    "-Dco.paralleluniverse.fibers.detectRunawayFibers=false",
    "-javaagent:${configurations.quasar.singleFile}" // =v, =d
]

// mainClassName = 'co.paralleluniverse.kotlin.actors1.PingPongKt'
mainClassName = 'co.paralleluniverse.kotlin.actors2.PingPongWithDeferKt'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.12'
}

defaultTasks 'run'
```

Some notes about the differences with your build file:

- Since I converted the tests to programs, I'm including the `application` plugin and its configuration (here, `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` and `mainClassName`) as well as setting the default Gradle task to `run`.
- In addition to the above, a gradle wrapper has been generated and pushed so that `./gradlew` is all you need on the command line, with no need to have a local Gradle installation (how to run it in an IDE depends on the IDE).
- You need to run the Quasar agent (or AoT instrumentation but using the agent here) so there's a `quasar` configuration pointing to the artifact that is then used to pass the `-javaagent:${configurations.quasar.singleFile}` JVM argument.
- Using Java 8 as Quasar has a specific optimized build for it.

Also note that there is now a [`1.0` branch of the `quasar-kotlin-jetbrains-webinar` project](https://github.com/circlespainter/quasar-kotlin-jetbrains-webinar) (which is now the `HEAD` one in fact), which contains the companion source code of [this guest webinar with IntelliJ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nmob2MB2Qo8), ported to the latest Kotlin and Quasar as well.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great answer, this helps a lot !!